# use awk for selecting a column having uneven string data

Tags: unix, awk

I have a table with data somehow like this

```
Student|Marks|remarks
------ | --- | ------
a      |50   |Need to improve
------ | --- | ------
b      |70   |Good performance 
------ | --- | ------
```

when am using `awk '((NR % 2) == 0) {printf "%-10s %-10s %10s\n", $1, $2, $3}' Filename.txt`, its just considering **Need** and **Good** from last column, Need suggestion on this as last remarks are also having uneven spaces.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Your comments under https://stackoverflow.com/a/46426840/1745001 say `My file is without borders '|' '-'` and `there are total 7 columns, out of which i need 3. But in these, data is inputted with spaces in few columns`, i.e. your actual input looks nothing like the sample input you posted in your question. So we have sample input that doesn't look like the real input, no sample output, and vague requirements. I am not optimistic about the future of this question.... :-). Once this one gets closed, read [ask] then try again.

Answer (score 2):

> when am using awk '((NR % 2) == 0) {printf "%-10s %-10s %10s\n", $1,
>   $2, $3}' Filename.txt, its just considering **Need** and **Good** from last
>   column, Need suggestion on this as last remarks are also having uneven
>   spaces.

- You need `-F'|'` or `-v FS='|'` then it takes care of uneven spaces,
- by default `awk` use single space as field separator, so only **Need** and **Good** from last column getting printed.

And

```
((NR % 2) == 0)
```

To

```
(NR % 2)
```

So that only only **odd rows** ( as far as I understand uneven ) will be printed

```
$ cat infile
Student|Marks|remarks
------ | --- | ------
a      |50   |Need to improve
------ | --- | ------
b      |70   |Good performance 
------ | --- | ------

$ awk -F'|' '(NR % 2){printf "%-10s %-10s %10s\n", $1, $2, $3}' infile
Student    Marks         remarks
a          50         Need to improve
b          70         Good performance
```

> **`awk` default behavior, which is single space as field separator**

```
$ awk 'NR==3{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)printf("Column-%d = $%d = %s\n",i,i,$i)}' infile
Column-1 = $1 = a
Column-2 = $2 = |50
Column-3 = $3 = |Need
Column-4 = $4 = to
Column-5 = $5 = improve
```

> **This is how `awk` behaves when you set `-F'|'`, pipe as field separator**

```
$ awk -F '|' 'NR==3{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)printf("Column-%d = $%d = %s\n",i,i,$i)}' infile
Column-1 = $1 = a      
Column-2 = $2 = 50   
Column-3 = $3 = Need to improve
```

Comment: My file is without borders '|' '-' now, still its selecting only Need and good

Comment: @Saurabhdv27 are these files are tab separated ? if so set `-F "\t"`

Comment: No the file is not tab separated, the spaces are also not evenly given

Comment: @Saurabhdv27 what is field separator between columns

Comment: spaces only..but there are total 7 columns, out of which i need 3.

But in these, data is inputted with spaces in few columns

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove the "borders", you don't have to care about the `FS` or `NR` stuff, give this sed one-liner a try:

```
sed -n 's/|/ /g; /[^- |]/p' file
```

Output with your test data:

```
Student Marks remarks
a       50    Need to improve
b       70    Good performance
```

### Update:

> No the borders are already removed now, but now i need to select 3rd column, but it only selects Need and good – Saurabhdv27

```
$  awk -F'|' 'NR>1&&$3~/[^ -]/{print $3}' file
Need to improve
Good performance
```

Comment: No the borders are already removed now, but now i need to select 3rd column, but it only selects Need and good

Comment: @Saurabhdv27 see the **Update** in answer.